# Subscribing to an Observable can be slow

Tags: c#, performance, observable, system.reactive

I'm having performance issues with my my current project, and have narrowed it down to its use of observables.

I have created the following console application to attempt to replicate this issue.

```cs
 var observable = new Subject<Data>();
 while (true)
 {
     var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
     stopwatch.Start();
 
     observable.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine );
 
     stopwatch.Stop();
     if(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds < 10) continue;
     Console.WriteLine($"Finished Subscribing, Took{stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
 }
```

Most of the time, this executes in 0ms, however if I filter the results and don't log anything under 10ms, you can see in some cases the results can sometimes even take up to 2 seconds to subscribe.

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this might be occurring, or should I recode my application and move away from using observables?

Edit:

I ran dotnet benchmarking with the following results
[image]

Edit 2:

This is a better example of my code, you will notice I create a unique subscription for each Item id, this is because in reality The Subscribe Method creates a new class with some custom state, and subscribers to multiple observables (e.g. a current Item Observable and a Profit observable) and whenever any of these change, it will merge them together into one object and output that object.

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using AutoFixture;
using DynamicData;
​
public class Program
{
    private static readonly SourceCache<Item, string> Source = new(item => item.itemId);
    private record Item(string itemId, int volume);
​
    private static readonly Fixture _fixture = new();

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Source.AsObservableCache().Connect()
            .WhereReasonsAre(ChangeReason.Add, ChangeReason.Remove)
            .SubscribeMany(Subscribe)
            .Subscribe();
​
        while (true)
        {
            var items = _fixture.CreateMany<Item>(1000).ToList();
            var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopWatch.Start();
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                Source.AddOrUpdate(item);
            }
            stopWatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"Finished Adding {items.Count} Items, Took {stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
        }
    }
​
    private static IDisposable Subscribe(Item item)
    {
        return Source.Connect()
            .Watch(item.itemId).Do(change => {  })
            .Subscribe();
    }
}
```

Note: This uses DynamicData here: https://github.com/reactivemarbles/DynamicData

You can see with this example, it doesnt perform as well over time[image]

You can also see the Benchmarks here
[image]

Comment: Just curious, what is your use case? In your actual code, do you perform many sequential subscriptions to observables? If that is the case, would throwing the subscribe out to an async method + callback help, or are you really just concerned that the subscription itself can randomly take a second or two because you want a quick response, even for a single subscription?

Comment: Did you compile this in Debug or Release? Do you have a "BenchmarkDotnet" - Version of this?

Comment: Are you running this code with high concurrency? As you can see [in the source code](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/2852824dc4beddf3b538837913187b6a5d9d08df/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Subjects/Subject.cs#L163C41-L215) there really isn't much to the `Subscribe` method other than add the observer to the list of observers. How much does "Most of the time, this executes in 0ms" mean?

Comment: So yeah, currently I load a bunch of data from a database, and subscribe to the observable for each record (about 10k ish) - Which takes like 10 minutes to complete due to the reasons above.

And im not running the code, there is essentially a for loop looping over the records and creating a subscription for each one. So it subscribes one at a time.

Comment: "How much does "Most of the time, this executes in 0ms" mean?" At a guess, around 90% of the time this is instant, but then sometimes it can take a few seconds to subscribe, which when you scale this to thousands of times, is really slowing the program down

Comment: @Fildor Taking a look at the benchmarks it looks like 20,000ms is spent doing System.Buffer._BulkMoveWithWriteBarrier

Comment: Have you checked for any correlations with GC?

Comment: _"and subscribe to the observable for each record (about 10k ish)"_ - TBH sounds like misuse of the pattern. Personally I think you should consider refactoring code so there is no need to manage that many subscriptions.

Comment: _"BulkMoveWithWriteBarrier"_ _sounds_ like thread safety collisions to me. Or at least something alike. GC was also one of my first thoughts from the looks of this.

Comment: Could you please share the code you're having trouble with? It would be really helpful to see your actual code in order to understand the issue better. If there is indeed a slowness in the `Subscribe` function, just looking at the code you provided won't allow us to do much other than agreeing with you. However, if you share your real code, we can work together to find a solution and optimize its performance.

Comment: When you put a global counter on the code to see when it starts to take longer than 10ms I find I can get 40,000+ subscriptions and I get my 10 at about 57448. It seems like you're just pushing the code beyond normal usage. Your real code would be awesome to see if we can make it faster.

Comment: Ive updated the code a bit to be closer to what im actually doing. Ive also added a paragraph to try explain why I am creating a new subscription for each unique Item.

Comment: @JDChris100 - Please provide a [mcve] of your real code. There is so much code missing in your new edit. And that code is way better than you original code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how your real code (not the benchmarking one) looks like, but the problem might be that the Subject you're using is a hot observable, which means it starts emitting values immediately upon subscription, regardless of whether there are any subscribers or not.

you have an infinite loop where you create a new Subject instance and subscribe to it repeatedly. This can lead to a buildup of subscriptions over time, which may impact performance.

Try to modify the code to ensure that you're subscribing to the Subject only once and reusing that subscription.

```
var observable = new Subject<Data>();
var subscription = observable.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);

while (true)
{
    var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();

    // Use the existing subscription

    stopwatch.Stop();
    if (stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds < 10) continue;
    Console.WriteLine($"Finished Subscribing, Took {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
}
```

Comment: I agree with your analysis of the sample code that the OP gave. It would be great to have the real code to see if the OP is actually doing the same thing. I don't think so; otherwise it would be a `O(n^2)` performance bottleneck. Real code would be great to see.

Comment: I updated the post above to try explain why im creating multiple observables. Since we are merging a bunch of objects into one, we assumed that having some local state and creating a new observable would be faster, rather than looping over thousands of objects and querying cache each time an object changes